# Zend 2 - Form element name with square brackets

Tags: forms, element, zend-framework2, brackets

I feel that Zend has decided to abandon the possibility of having the name of a form element with square bracket like something['otherone'].

In Zend Framework 1, you could make $element->setBelongsTo ('piece'), if you wanted to display an input element of style

I read the documentation and searched the ZF2 code, and this feature seems to have disappeared.

Why?!

Is it in Zend Framework 2 a way to do this.

Matthew if you pass by here, i need your help!

Answer (score 2):

In Zend Framework 1 you have to use setBelong to method because zf was removing brackets from attribiute name. In ZF2 you can use brackets in name so you don't need to use setBelong to method.

```
use Zend\Form\Element;
use Zend\Form\View\Helper;

$text = new Element\Text('something[otherone]');

$viewHelperElement = new Helper\FormText();
echo $viewHelperElement->render($text);
```

Outpu will be:

```
<input type="text" name="something[otherone]" value="">
```

Comment: LoL, yeah I know it's exactly what I 've seen and thank you for your answer.

But the real problem now is that validation of this kind element do not work and it couldn't.